# This URL validation is not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a code that I which is taken from another stackoverflow post,

here it is,

```
 function validate_url($url)
 {
     $pattern = "/^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([w]{2}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?/";
     if (!preg_match($pattern, $url))
     {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_url', 'The URL you entered is not correctly formatted.'); 
         return false;
     }

     return false;
 }
```

It is not working properly. It is allowing URL without (something like) .com or .in (anything after dot).

Meaning, it should allow proper the URL as 
  http://something.com or 
  http://www.something.in or

but not
  http://something (without .in or .com or any other) or 
   something   or
  www.something

I don't know much about regular expressions. Please help me..

Comment: 'something' *is* a valid URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at this site:

https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

It contains a lot of different URL validation regex.

The one from Diego Perini:

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

seems so much better than the one used by filter_var.

Comment: Thanks, really there are lots of regex, the one I used is from https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) `filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);` for validating your urls.
Here you can find all types of [validation types](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) you can use.
If you want to require the `http(s)` you can add use this.

```
filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
$url = "http://something";

if ((!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) && @fopen($url,"r")) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Or use this

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example';

if(validateURL($url)){
       echo "Valid";
    }else{
        echo "invalid";
    }

function validateURL($URL) {
      $pattern_1 = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";
      $pattern_2 = "/^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";       
      if(preg_match($pattern_1, $URL) || preg_match($pattern_2, $URL)){
        return true;
      } else{
        return false;
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regular expression

```
$url = 'http://something.com';

$regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
$regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass
$regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP
$regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port
$regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path
$regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query
$regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor

if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $url)) {
    echo "Matched";
} else {
    echo "Not Matched";
}
```